# plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found Android studio

Tags: android

I'm getting "***plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found***" error in my app after adding one library project in my app, but now I removed that library project from my app but still same error is persist. I googled a lot and tried almost all the solution but yet unable to resolve this error. For more information, please check the following "app module's build.gradle"--

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lemo.wikinews"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':easyAndroidAnimationsLibrary')
    compile project(':liveSdk')
    compile project(':main')
    compile project(':zbarSample')
    compile project(':stickyHeaderLibrary')
    compile project(':starBar')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':ffmpeg4android_lib')
    compile project(':socialNetworkingLib')    
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile files('libs/nmdp_speech_kit.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')   
    compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
    compile files('libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar')
    compile files('libs/devsmartandroid.jar')   
    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.6.0-beta'

    compile files('libs/google-api-services--v1-1.3.0-beta.jar')   
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.4.jar')    
    compile group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-commonshttp4', version: '1.2'

    compile group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-core', version: '1.2.1.2'

    compile group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-jetty6', version: '1.2.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

  '4.4-alpha1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'


version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3')
            {
                exclude module: "httpclient"
            }
}
```

And below is my top level 'builg.gradle'--

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Also please let me know if I can provide more information to understand the problem. Thank you.

Comment: update the gradle version to new..before that check,restart the project by using this... **file->invalid caches/restart** option.

Comment: what version of gradle wrapper are you using?

Comment: @Aram Tchekrekjian version of gradle wrapper is 2.8

Comment: did you try doing what @brahmyadigopula suggested? _restart the project by using this... file->invalid caches/restart option_

Comment: @ Aram Tchekrekjian Yes I tried that but not working (Same error).

Comment: Facing same issue. @Leo Wiki Have u got the answer..?

Comment: @Dnyanesh M Not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Bellow is my way to resolve a import problem,the project use a old studio plugin. Forgive my poor English.

Edit your top moudle build.gradle ,edit gradle plugin to your studio's have . then maybe show this,
Error:Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SelectCityDome\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.14.1-all.zip 
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project
Gradle settings  follow the step fix it.

JUST SEE THIS PICTURE

[image]